# Is there a way to show Android Acivity stacks?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

Are there any tools for displaying the current task's Activity stack? I'd like to do some debugging, e.g.: check to see if a specific Activity always starts in a new task, and things like that. But i couldn't find any tooling for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally run "adb shell dumpsys activity" against the emulator or device, that dumps a whole bunch of info, including the activity stack. Takes a little poking around to understand all the info, but it's there.

If there is a way to get it from DDMS, someone please post it. I haven't run across it yet.

Comment: Thanks, that was the thing I was looking for! Not that easy to read but I's ok.